# XSLT to convert xml to csv and repeat a sibling for every record

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

Below is the XML file that is used as a source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<billing-log>
  <log-start-date>2012-08-17T00:00:00-05:00</log-start-date>
  <player-name>Player1</player-name>
  <schema-version>1</schema-version>
  <player-uuid>12345</player-uuid>
  <log-end-date>2012-08-17T23:59:59.999-05:00</log-end-date>
  <entry>
     <page>Page1</page>
     <path>Path1</path>
     <in>2012-08-16T23:59:52.170-05:00</in>
     <out>2012-08-17T00:00:00.186-05:00</out>
  </entry>
  <entry>
     <page>Page2</page>
     <path>Path2</path>
     <in>2012-08-17T00:00:00.186-05:00</in>
     <out>2012-08-17T00:00:08.561-05:00</out>
  </entry>
</billing-log>
```

The xsl file I am using is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="log-start-date"></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="player-name"></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="schema-version"></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="player-uuid"></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="log-end-date"></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//entry">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(page)"/><xsl:text/>
        <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(path)"/><xsl:text/>
        <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(in)"/><xsl:text/>
        <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(out)"/><xsl:text/>
        <xsl:text>"&#10;&#13;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping = "yes" >
</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I feed these into the following c# console application to convert it into a CSV and write it out to a file.:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

namespace xml2csv
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 3)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Wrong number of aruguments");
                return -1;
            }

            string xmlFile = args[0];
            string xslFile = args[1];
            string outputFile = args[2];

            //Create a new XML document and load the XML file
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(xmlFile);
            //Create an XSLT object and load the XSLT file            
            XslCompiledTransform xslTran = new XslCompiledTransform();
            xslTran.Load(xslFile);
            // This is for generating the output
            XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(outputFile, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
            //Apply the transformation and write disk
            xslTran.Transform(xmlDoc, null, writer);
            //Close the writer
            writer.Close();

            return 1;

        }
    }
}
```

The result it produces is:

```
"Page1","Path1","2012-08 16T23:59:52.170-05:00","2012-08-17T00:00:00.186-05:00"
"Page2","Path2","2012-08-17T00:00:00.186-05:00","2012-08-17T00:00:08.561-05:00"
```

What I want is to prepend the sibling node value for log-end-date to ever record for the entry node.  So the output would look like this:

```
"2012-08-17T23:59:59.999-05:00","Page1","Path1","2012-08 16T23:59:52.170-05:00","2012-08-17T00:00:00.186-05:00"
"2012-08-17T23:59:59.999-05:00","Page2","Path2","2012-08-17T00:00:00.186-05:00","2012-08-17T00:00:08.561-05:00"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',normalize-space(../log-end-date),'&quot;')"/>
```

as the first child of your template for `entry`.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you very much.  This is my first xslt project and I was up against a hugh deadline.

Comment: @user1813171 - You're very welcome. Please consider accepting this answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it. Thanks!